# How to add Positives to negative numbers in php?

Tags: php, math, geocoding

This is my math:

```
$range = 0.43218;
$this->location['longitude'] = -78.852972745895;
$this->location['latitude'] = 42.879424080703;

$minlong = $this->location['longitude']-$range;
$maxlong = $this->location['longitude']+$range;
$minlat = $this->location['latitude']-$range;
$maxlat = $this->location['latitude']+$range;
```

But i end up with this:

```
$minlong = -79.285152745895;
$maxlong = -78.420792745895;
$minlat = 42.447244080703;
$maxlat = 43.311604080703;
```

Im trying to end up with a range in between the two original latitude and longitude, can anyone help me with my math. I have been working all day with numbers and they are killing me!

Comment: i then use these to get the data from the database, my sql is Select * from `Stores` where (`Longitude` BETWEEN '-79.285152745895' and '-78.420792745895') and (`Latitude` BETWEEN '42.447244080703' and '43.311604080703') But this returns nothing although there should be 3 resutls

Comment: Looks good to me. What's wrong with your current result?

Comment: Heres a link to my 3 results that should show up http://ft.trillian.im/bf33102d41b540ba92d5daba6e50e69018e5dc8a/6ipqYDjaNCHU9UuzI0It1gyTcB1eH.jpg

Comment: It looks like you did a good job of adding and subtracting numbers. So what's the problem?

Comment: Algebra or programming question?

Comment: Personally, I think it would be better to do a circle with a diameter of $range instead of an ugly square. Just sayin'... Don't forget to account for the curvature of the earth. It tends to throw results off a bit over large areas.

Comment: What data type are the Latitude and Longitude fields in your database?

Comment: geometry fail... rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: you need to get the lats and longs with some radius to the given lat long only adding subtracting will not give the lat long within the range

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer, seems like i have to just flip them

```
if($this->location['longitude'] < 0){ /* Flip if negative */
    $minlong = $this->location['longitude']+$range;
    $maxlong = $this->location['longitude']-$range;
}else{
    $minlong = $this->location['longitude']-$range;
    $maxlong = $this->location['longitude']+$range;
}
if($this->location['latitude'] < 0){ /* Flip if negative */
    $minlat = $this->location['latitude']+$range;
    $maxlat = $this->location['latitude']-$range;
}else{
    $minlat = $this->location['latitude']-$range;
    $maxlat = $this->location['latitude']+$range;
}
```

Comment: So "min" means "closer to the equator or prime meridian", not numerically lower.